# Cell spacing in between cells only

Tags: html, css

How can I use cell spacing so that there is only space between cells and not on the outside of the row, e.g.

```
NO SPACE HERE | CELL | SPACE HERE | CELL | NO SPACE HERE
```

I can't use padding as I have a background. Same reason as to why I cant use a transparent border.

Is there a solution? Inline CSS only too (its an email).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to combine `border-spacing: (x)px` with `margin: (-x)px)` with `width: calc(100% + (columns * x)px)`.

Example:

```
<table style="width:calc(100% + 8px);border-spacing:4px;margin:-4px">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrmills/zoqhdb0z/

Comment: Thanks but negative margin probably will not work across all email clients.

Comment: this isn't good for email

Comment: Can you put it inside another div with `overflow:hidden`?